# How to combine binding fragments without wrapping them in an XML literal

Tags: html, scala, dom, scala.js, binding.scala

I'm trying to combine 2 binding fragments into one without recourse to an englobing XML literal.

See the following code:

```scala
@dom def a = <div><p>a</p></div>
@dom def b = <div><p>b</p></div>

@dom def block = {
  // <div>
  {a.bind}
  {b.bind}
  // </div>
}
```

See [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/QFYj6Xs/1)

As expected, this does not work, only *b* is displayed.

What I'm looking for here is a way to combine 2 fragments into one, through a function with this signature (for example)

```
combine: Binding[Node] x Binding[Node] -> Binding[BindingSeq[Node]]
```

How is it possible ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/9cLgxbN/1

```
def block = Binding(Constants(a.bind, b.bind))
```

or

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/9cLgxbN/6

```
def block = Binding(Constants(a, b).map(_.bind))
```

The latter one is able to partially update, while the former one is not.

#### For `BindingSeq`:

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/9cLgxbN/7

```
@dom def a = <div><p>a</p></div><div>b</div>
@dom def b = <div><p>c</p></div><div>d</div>
def block = Binding(Constants((a.bind.all.bind ++ b.bind.all.bind): _*))
```

or

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/9cLgxbN/8

```
def block = Binding(Constants(a, b).flatMap(_.bind))
```

Comment: Awesome. That's really simple.

Comment: Nice. I was wondering how to combine several BindingSeq into one. You just brought me the answer :-) Thx.